# JAVA, IntelliJ IDEA и ошибка Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jframe

Я очень, очень глупый новечёк. У меня есть ошибка но нет решения(((( A Google отказываеться помогать(((( Пожалуйста, сделайте это за него

Main

```
package com.company;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     GUI window =  new GUI();
     javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(window);
    }
}
```

GUI

```
package com.company;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI implements Runnable {
    JFrame frame;
    public void run() {
        initframe();

    }

    private void initframe() {
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("Life game");
        frame.setSize(250, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Сама ошибка

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.company.GUI.initframe(GUI.java:12)
    at com.company.GUI.run(GUI.java:7)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Забыли выделить память под объект

Comment: Будьте добры объяснить, как? И почему у других этот же код работает?

Comment: Все, понял! Спасибо!

Comment: Как вижу , все хорошо ) Удачи в разработке )